# Can't find compiled executable in Linux terminal

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I've created a hello world program in c++ and tried to compile it in c++ like this.

```bash
[aleksf@ic-ifi-rh8-026 cpp]$ g++ testing.cpp -o testing
```

I know that the testing file was created because

```bash
[aleksf@ic-ifi-rh8-026 cpp]$ ls -A
testing  testing.cpp
```

But when I try to execute the file it can't find it.

```bash
[aleksf@ic-ifi-rh8-026 cpp]$ .\testing
bash: .testing: command not found...
```

I don't understand whats gone wrong as this is what I've been told works.

Comment: You can use the command `locate testing` to find the created executable on your pc.

Comment: Also, check that when you executable using `locate testing`, it has the permission to be executed.

Comment: `./testing` and not `.testing`, nor with backslash. BTW if you take some more time to format your question, more people will read it.

Comment: The problem is tha backslash `\t` is `t`

Answer (score 2):

Linux does not use \ it uses / for directory paths. Try `./testing`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Russel have pointed out, you need to use forward slash: `./testing`

The file you're trying to run also needs to have the executable mode bit set. You can fix that by running: `chmod +x testing`